# Find incorrect records by Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find records where the personID is associated to the incorrect SoundFile(String). I am trying to search for incorrect records among all personID's, not just one specific one. Here are my example tables:

```
TASKS-                                
PersonID    SoundFile(String)
123         D10285.18001231234.mp3
123         D10236.18001231234.mp3
123         D10237.18001231234.mp3
123         D10212.18001231234.mp3
123         D12415.18001231234.mp3
**126         D19542.18001231234.mp3
126         D10235.18001234567.mp3
126         D19955.18001234567.mp3

RECORDINGS-
PhoneNumber(Distinct Records)
18001231234
18001234567
```

So in this example, I am trying to find all records like the one that I indented. The majority of the soundfiles like '%18001231234%' are associated to PersonID 123, but this one record is PersonID 126. I need to find all records where for all distinct numbers from the Recordings table, the PersonID(s) is not the majority. 
Let me know if you need more information!
         Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you post the query you are using?

Comment: what criteria are you using to determine if a record is "incorrect" ?

Comment: The phone number in the middle of Soundfile should only ever have one personID. So for every record where soundfile contains the number 18001231234, the PersonID should always be 123 because that is the majority. So our clients call in and leave messages to attach to tasks. They enter their PIN(personID) when they call in, sometimes they hit the wrong key even though it asks them to confirm. Hopefully that gives you some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; WITH distinctRecordings AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT PhoneNumber
  FROM Recordings
),
PersonCounts as (
  SELECT t.PersonID, dr.PhoneNumber, COUNT(*) AS num
  FROM
    Tasks t
    JOIN distinctRecordings dr
      ON t.SoundFile LIKE '%' + dr.PhoneNumber + '%'
  GROUP BY t.PersonID, dr.PhoneNumber
)
SELECT t.PersonID, t.SoundFile
FROM PersonCounts pc1
  JOIN PersonCounts pc2
    ON pc2.PhoneNumber = pc1.PhoneNumber
    AND pc2.PersonID <> pc1.PersonID
    AND pc2.Num < pc1.Num
  JOIN Tasks t
    ON t.PersonID = pc2.PersonID
    AND t.SoundFile LIKE '%' + pc2.PhoneNumber + '%'
```

### [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c60f/6)

To summarize what this does... the first CTE, `distinctRecordings`,  is just a distinct list of the Phone Numbers in `Recordings`.

Next, `PersonCounts` is a count of phone numbers associated with the records in `Tasks` for each `PersonID`.

This is then joined to itself to find any duplicates, and selects whichever duplicate has the smaller count... this is then joined back to `Tasks` to get the offending `soundFile` for that person / phone number.

(If your schema had some minor improvements made to it, this query would have been much simpler...)

Answer (score 0):

here you go, receiving all pairs  (`PersonID`, `PhoneNumber`) where the person has less entries with the given phone number than the person with the maximum entries. note that the query doesn't cater for multiple persons on par within a group.

```
    select agg.pid
         , agg.PhoneNumber
      from (
                select MAX(c) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY c DESC ) OVER ( PARTITION BY rt.PhoneNumber ) cmax
                     , rt.PhoneNumber
                     , rt.PersonID      pid
                     , rt.c
                  from (
                                select r.PhoneNumber
                                     , t.PersonID
                                     , count(*)     c
                                  from recordings   r
                            inner join tasks        t   on ( r.PhoneNumber = regexp_replace(t.SoundFile, '^[^.]+\.([^.]+)\.[^.]+$', '\1' ) )
                              group by r.PhoneNumber
                                     , t.PersonID
                       ) rt
           ) agg
     where agg.c < agg.cmax
         ;
```

caveat: the solution is in oracle syntax though the operations should be in the current sql standard (possibly apart from `regexp_replace`, which might not matter too much since your sound file data seems to follow a fixed-position structure ).